# Kotlin Android studio 3.1 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin to develop an android app and everything was working fine but from past two days, while running the app I am getting the following Error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.diagnostics.DiagnosticUtils
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:244)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:222)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:143)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.safeGetType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:89)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.resolveInitializerType(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:159)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.access$resolveInitializerType(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.DeferredType.getDelegate(DeferredType.java:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.computeDeferredType(BodyResolver.java:946)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveProperty(BodyResolver.java:707)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolvePropertyDeclarationBodies(BodyResolver.java:751)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBehaviorDeclarationBodies(BodyResolver.java:116)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBodies(BodyResolver.java:241)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:162)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:451)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:218)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:518)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:400)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:895)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:925)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:894)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

in my projects build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha09'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31'
}
```

in app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.31'
}
```

first it was stable android studio version 3.1 the issue started occuring and then updated it to canary 3.2 canary 9 but the issue still remains.